# Measuring distance between guides in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, guides

In Fireworks, I can hold shift to show the distance between two guides, is it possible to do so in Inkscape?

If not, what is the option left to position everything symmetrically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can double-click on a guide to see its properties. There you can specify the absolute position, or a relative displacement.

Enabling guide-snapping, you may for example drop a new guide onto an existing one, double click and then move it by a precise amount.

You also have *Path to guides* (shift-G), which converts an object into the boundary guides.

*Extensions -> custom -> custom guides* may also help.

Comment: Is this custom guides extension the same as this one in [github](https://github.com/sambody/inkscape-guide-tools) ?

Comment: The inkscape-guide-tools you linked looks neat, and is not the one included in Inkscape.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use inkscape-guide-tools to add centered guides to an object, it does nothing. And the extension you mentioned (custom guides) didn't come with my Inkscape installation (Windows 0.92.2). I'm still looking for a quick and productive way to measure distances with guides, add centered guides, etc.

Comment: For now, I'll be doing what you initially said, placing one guide over the other, do the math and the relative displacement, until something faster comes out.